# Lambda timeout when adding an edge using nodejs to aws neptune using gremlin

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, gremlin, amazon-neptune

We are trying to add an edge between two vertex using nodejs running in Lambda and aws neptune. 
We can easily add a vertex, but when we try to add an edge, our Lambda timesout. Our timeout is set to 20 seconds.

Here is the code.

```
async function updateDoc (db, dataTmp, now, id, callback, logData, errorData) {
  try {
    console.log('inside updateDoc function')   

    console.log(dataTmp)        

    var user1 = await g.V().hasLabel('user').has('userId', dataTmp.userId).valueMap().unfold().toList()
console.log('user1', user1)
var user2 = await g.V().hasLabel('user').has('userId', dataTmp.trustedUserId).valueMap().unfold().toList()
console.log('user2', user2)
const edgeAdded =  await g.V().hasLabel('user').has('userId', dataTmp.userId).as('u').V().hasLabel('user').has('userId', dataTmp.trustedUserId).as('tu').addE('trust').from('u').to('tu').next()
console.log('edgeAdded making asynch', edgeAdded)
    // dc.close()        
    return callback(null)
  } catch (error) {
    return callback(null)
  }    

}
```

Here is the output from lambda

{8 items
"type":"AddTrustedUser"

"userId":"5ed1cd97ee7ac30008b86a8c"

"trustedUserId":"5ed1cd98ee7ac30008b86a8d"

"dupId":"r54sw17ND"

"time":"2020-05-30T03:06:02.632Z"

"initTime":"2020-05-30T03:06:02.632Z"

"lastTime":"2020-05-30T03:06:02.632Z"

"logsGroupName":"AddTrustedUser"
}

user1 [

Map { 'firstName' => [ 'jaat' ] },

Map { 'userId' => [ '5ed1cd97ee7ac30008b86a8c' ] }

]

user2 [

Map { 'firstName' => [ 'maat' ] },

Map { 'userId' => [ '5ed1cd98ee7ac30008b86a8d' ] }

]

REPORT  Duration: 20020.15 ms   Billed Duration: 20000 ms   Memory Size: 1024 MB    Max Memory Used: 103 MB Init Duration: 745.55 ms     [+20021ms]
3 minutes ago cafbd19c-7b7a-4acb-b3fb-134bb51f054f Task timed out after 20.02 seconds [+20021ms]

Any pointers on what we are doing wrong.

Comment: I don't see a `terminal` step at the end of the query such as `iterate()` or `toList()` also given it is an async function would you not want to `await` the query?

Comment: Thanks Kelvin for a quick response. We will try with await and next and update here. Thanks for writing the book, its a great reference.

Comment: We are still seeing timeouts during addE query

Comment: When adding the edge rather than end the traversal with `next()` have you tried `iterate()` or `toList()` ?

Comment: I have not tried iterate() or toList(), but changing from() to from_() fixed the issue. http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#from-step . I was thinking only python needs from_, it seems nodejs needs it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing from() to from_() fixed the issue. 
tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#from-step